# Promise.allSettled in babel ES6 implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-promise

I'm using `babel` to transpile my `node.js@0.10.x` code and I'm stuck with promises.

I need `allSettled`-type functionality that I could use in `q` and `bluebird` or `angular.$q` for example.

On babel's core-js `Promise`, there is no `allSettled` method.

Currently I'm using `q.allSettled` as a workaround:

`import { allSettled } from 'q';`

Is there something like that in babel polyfill? Alternatively, which is a good algorithm for me to try to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alternatively, which is a good algorithm for me to try to implement?

1. create a new promise with an [executor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
2. use a counter/result array in the scope of the executor
3. register a then() callback with each parent promise saving the results in the array
4. resolve/reject promise from step 1 when counter indicates that all parent promises are done

Comment: Nice, though for now I'll stick to using Q (which is probably doing the same).

Comment: With regard to your step 4, how would I ever know to reject the new promise?

Comment: @torazaburo you're right, you would never reject, that's the point of allSettled :)
Maybe some timeout, but that's a different use case and not reflecting what q.allSettled does.

Answer (score 44):

### 2019 Answer

There was [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-allSettled) to add this function to the ECMAScript standard, and it has been accepted! Check out the [`Promise.allSettled` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) for details.

### Original Answer

If you take a look at the [implementation of q.allSettled](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/01252cbe917178f5935cbe2a1ab43e12934c7057/q.js#L1693-L1703) you'll see it's actually quite simple to implement. Here's how you might implement it using ES6 Promises:

```
function allSettled(promises) {
    let wrappedPromises = promises.map(p => Promise.resolve(p)
        .then(
            val => ({ status: 'fulfilled', value: val }),
            err => ({ status: 'rejected', reason: err })));
    return Promise.all(wrappedPromises);
}
```

Comment: Michael - I'm looking for a solution like this as well (Promise.all that executes all the promises and then capture all the errors in an array) - in order to use your allSettled function, would I do an npm install q and then do const q = require('q'); in my application?

Comment: @RogerDodger The code I wrote is assuming you're running an ES6 capable runtime, so basically any current browser or modern version of Node. Or you're using a promise polyfill. If either is the case, then you don't need to import Q or any other promise library.

Comment: Darn, in Feb 2020 Edge still doesn't support `Promise.allSettled`, thanks for the polyfill from your original answer!

Comment: Why wrapping a promise in `Promise.resolve(p)`? to be sure that it is definitely a promise?

Comment: @OlehZiniak Yes, exactly. Could be convenient if you have a mixed array of promises and non-promise values. Another option would be to have allSettled throw an error in that case.

Answer (score 14):

2020 answer:

What the other answers are trying to do is to implement `Promise.allSettled` themselves. This was already done by the [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) project.

What you need to do is to make babel polyfill `Promise.allSettled` for you via [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js). The way you configure it to do so is through [`@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) like so:

```js
presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: {version: 3, proposals: true},
    }],
],
```

In your build artifact this will add a call to `require("core-js/modules/esnext.promise.all-settled")` which monkeypatches the `.allSettled` function to the promises API.

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
const allSettled = promises =>
  Promise.all(promises.map(promise => promise
    .then(value => ({ state: 'fulfilled', value }))
    .catch(reason => ({ state: 'rejected', reason }))
  ));
```

Or if you insist on polyfilling it:

```
if (Promise && !Promise.allSettled) {
  Promise.allSettled = function (promises) {
    return Promise.all(promises.map(function (promise) {
      return promise.then(function (value) {
        return { state: 'fulfilled', value: value };
      }).catch(function (reason) {
        return { state: 'rejected', reason: reason };
      });
    }));
  };
}
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/robhicks/es2015-Promise.allSettled)

Comment: This is pretty good (and I'm using it) but there's one bug in this polyfill. The property returned [should be `status` and not `state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled). I issued a pull request here with a modified version of the polyfill which is still backward compatible (but have an ideal version which is missing the `state` field in the PR, too): https://github.com/robhicks/es2015-Promise.allSettled/pull/1

Comment: @chunk_split thanks, I upgraded `core.js`  to `v3` so now I have native `allSettled` and don't need the polyfill any more.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at something similar, I have Newsletter service and in my case I wanted my allSettled promise to resolve with an array of all the results (rejections and resolutions), *IN ORDER*, once all the email_promises are settled (all the emails had gone out):

```
Newsletter.prototype.allSettled = function(email_promises) {
    var allSettledPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Keep Count
        var counter = email_promises.length;

        // Keep Individual Results in Order
        var settlements = [];
        settlements[counter - 1] = undefined;

        function checkResolve() {
            counter--;
            if (counter == 0) {
                resolve(settlements);
            }
        }

        function recordResolution(index, data) {
            settlements[index] = {
                success: true,
                data: data
            };
            checkResolve();
        }

        function recordRejection(index, error) {
            settlements[index] = {
                success: false,
                error: error
            };
            checkResolve();
        }

        // Attach to all promises in array
        email_promises.forEach(function(email_promise, index) {
            email_promise.then(recordResolution.bind(null, index))
                .catch(recordRejection.bind(null, index));
        });
    });
    return allSettledPromise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my implementation will be below

```
Promise.prototype.myAllSettled = function (arr = []) {
  return new Promise(function processIterable(resolve, reject) {
    let result = [];
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      item
        .then((value) => {
          result.push({ status: "fulfilled", value: value });
          if (arr.length === result.length) resolve(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          result.push({ status: "rejected", reason: `${err}` });
          if (arr.length === result.length) resolve(result);
        });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi Vikas, this is a bit old question. Right now you don't even need a library for that, it's supported natively in all major browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: but not in electron

Comment: This has the issue that it reorders the promises based on the one that is completed first, this is not how the native function behaves

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take at the same functionality: [spex.batch](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/blob/master/docs/code/batch.md)

The [source code](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/blob/master/lib/ext/batch.js) would be too much to re-post here, so here's just an example from the [batch processing](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/blob/master/docs/concept/batch.md) of how to use it:

```
var spex = require('spex')(Promise);

// function that returns a promise;
function getWord() {
    return Promise.resolve("World");
}

// function that returns a value;
function getExcl() {
    return '!';
}

// function that returns another function;
function nested() {
    return getExcl;
}

var values = [
    123,
    "Hello",
    getWord,
    Promise.resolve(nested)
];

spex.batch(values)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("DATA:", data);
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log("REASON:", reason);
    });
```

This outputs:

```
DATA: [ 123, 'Hello', 'World', '!' ]
```

Now let's make it fail by changing `getWord` to this:

```
function getWord() {
    return Promise.reject("World");
}
```

Now the output is:

```
REASON: [ { success: true, result: 123 },
  { success: true, result: 'Hello' },
  { success: false, result: 'World' },
  { success: true, result: '!' } ]
```

i.e. the entire array is settled, reporting index-bound results.

And if instead of reporting the entire reason we call `getErrors()`:

```
console.log("REASON:", reason.getErrors());
```

then the output will be:

```
REASON: [ 'World' ]
```

This is just to simplify quick access to the list of errors that occurred.