# Trying to write alternative for promise.allsettled using async.each

Tags: javascript, node.js

I earlier had a code with `Promise.allSettled(payoutPromises);`

But it couldn't work on our server because it has a version 10 for nodejs.

This is what I came up with to do something similar , using some blogs as reference .

```
  async.each(transactions, function(transaction, iteratorCB) {
    payoutPromises.push(function(callback) {
      ValidationHelper.bankPayoutTransfer(transaction, 'neft').then((data) => {
        response.push({"status":"fulfilled","value":data});
        callback(null, data);
      }).catch((_err) => {
        response.push({"status":"rejected","reason":_err});
      });
    });
    iteratorCB();
  }, function() {
    async.parallel(payoutPromises, function(err, results) {
      console.log(err,results);
    });
  })
```

The problem I am facing is I want to wait for this async block before executing the rest of the code, like we can using a then after `Promise.allSettled`
I am a noob in terms of nodejs and working on it since a year.

Comment: Have you had a look a [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569182)?

Comment: Also, [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.allsettled) seems to be pretty popular. Maybe you could have a look at the source code for some inspiration

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Yes that module works, I installed that as a package and added in package.json to deploy. Thanks a Tonne. You can add it as an answer.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek npm install promise.allsettled , seems to be easy and appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

Try implementing [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.allsettled). It seems to be pretty popular and it does the thing you want to implement.