# Typescript target & library configuration to use Promise.allSettled on older browsers

Tags: typescript, webpack, promise, ecmascript-5, tsconfig

I am using typescript version 4.3.5 and node version 14.18.1. I am compiling my code targeting old as well as new browsers (`target=es5` in tsconfig). I am using Promise.all as well as Promise.allSettled both in my source code.

On older browsers, specifically *Safari on IPhone 8, IOS version 11*, I am getting client side errors with Promise.allSettled.

As per my understanding, when using `target=es5`, typescript should compile to make the code compatible with older devices hence Promise.allSettled should work. Please help me understand the issue! Following is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "ES2020.Promise",
      "dom",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "typings/node.d.ts",
    "typings/modules.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.scss.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the question [Why do I need a polyfill with Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633273/why-do-i-need-a-polyfill-with-typescript), TypeScript doesn't automatically provide backwards-compatibility implementations (["polyfills"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming))). Consequently, the [`target` tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) does less than you think it would: It only rewrites *syntax* like arrow functions and generators, not *libraries* like Promise. In fact, the only reason you can resolve Promise.allSettled in the first place is that you've specifically listed `"ES2020.Promise"` in your [`lib` list](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib), which tells TypeScript that in your environment you can assume you have access to ES2020 Promises ([specifically `Promise.allSettled`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es2020.promise.d.ts)).

From those [`lib` docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib), emphasis mine:

> You may want to change these [`lib` entries] for a few reasons:
>
> - Your program doesn’t run in a browser, so you don’t want the "dom" type definitions
> - Your runtime platform provides certain JavaScript API objects (maybe through polyfills), but doesn’t yet support the full syntax of a given ECMAScript version
> - **You have polyfills or native implementations for some, but not all, of a higher level ECMAScript version**

As in the question [Promise.allSettled in babel ES6 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30569182/1426891), you have several options to provide a polyfill yourself, but a notable one is [es.promise.all-settled.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.promise.all-settled.js) in [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js). You can integrate those into your Webpack build using [the `polyfills` entry point](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#loading-polyfills) pointing to a short polyfill-import-only JS file, though the suggestion to use `babel-polyfill` has been [deprecated in favor of `core-js/stable`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill/).

You would need to `import` or `require` one of these:

- [`core-js/stable/promise/all-settled`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-promise)
- [`promise.allsettled`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.allsettled)
- [`ts-polyfill/lib/es2020-promise`](https://github.com/ryanelian/ts-polyfill) (uses `core-js` anyway)